# not getting plot while using ipython in miniconda

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, miniconda

I am not getting any plot when i am using matplotlib in ipython.here is the code:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set() # use Seaborn styles
births.pivot_table('births', index='year', columns='gender', aggfunc='sum').plot()
plt.ylabel('total births per year');
```

and i am getting an output as :

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

this is the output i am getting while running the code:
[image: this is the output i am getting while running the code]

Comment: any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about `plt.show()`?

Comment: Similar behavior has happened to me on IPython. I restarted IPython and then it worked.

Comment: @PéterLeéh it is still showing the same result.

Comment: I tried restarting Ipython too, but it didn't work

Comment: if i use plt.savefig("image.png")  it works but i want it it to display at the same place as my code.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance of miniconda, but it just looks like the command window to me. Are you really in an iPython editor? Command window won't show matplotlib outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting the answer when i use %matplotlib at the starting of the code.Some how this works for me.[image]